# Google Translate API and Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-translate

I'm  using Google Translate API in a java project with Google App Engine.

On my machine, on local, there is no problem with Google Translate. But when I deploy the application, I got this :

```
"{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":
"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to 
activate the API for your project."}],"code":403,"message":
"Access Not Configured. 
Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."}}"
```

- Google Translate API is enabled
- Billing is enabled

Comment: Go to  [google code](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and then revert to the old interface when they prompt you with the option. Then edit allowed IPs and include your ipv6 address.

Comment: What are you talking about ? IPV6 from google endpoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my partially my using external libraries :

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Hope it's help